# Check if ID from array has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class

i have a windows like interface and when u click a desktop icon, a windows (set to display: hidden;) gets the class "visible".

```
.visible {
    display: initial !important;
}
```

i have multiple desktop icons, and multiple windows.
There is also a taskbar, with the same icons. i want these to be highlighted when the corresponding windows is set to "visible".

```
.taskbar_icon.hover {
    background: #9a3233;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

the way i wanted to do this is by putting the IDs of the windows in an array. 
then check if any of those windows have the class "visible". 
and if they do, add a class of "hover" to the corresponding taskbar icon.

this is what i got so far.

Jquery :

```
window.setInterval(function () {
var windows = ["#explorer", "#chrome", "#txt_editor"];
console.log(windows);
    if ( $(windows).hasClass('visible') ) {
        $(this + '_taskbar').addClass('hover');
    }
    else {
        $(this + '_taskbar').removeClass('hover');
    };
}, 100);
```

HTML :
Desktop icon

```
<div id="desktop">
        <a href="#_" target="#explorer" class="desktop_icon"><img src="img/icons/folder.png"></a>
        <a href="#_" target="#chrome" class="desktop_icon"><img src="img/icons/chrome.png"></a>
        <a href="#_" target="#txt_editor" class="desktop_icon"><img src="img/icons/word.png"></a>
    </div>
```

Windows

```
<div id="explorer" class="window"></div>
<div id="chrome" class="window"></div>
<div id="txt_editor" class="window"></div>
```

Taskbar

```
<div id="taksbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#_" target="#explorer" id="explorer_taskbar" class=" taskbar_icon"><img src="img/icons/folder_taskbar.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#_" target="#chrome" id="chrome_taskbar" class=" taskbar_icon"><img src="img/icons/chrome.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#_" target="#txt_editor" id="txt_editor_taskbar" class=" taskbar_icon"><img src="img/icons/word_taskbar.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate using [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method over array to check whether that particular ID selector has class visible or not like:

```
var windows = ["#explorer", "#chrome", "#txt_editor"];
$.each(windows , function( index, value ) {
   alert( index + ": " + value );
   if ( $(value).hasClass("visible")){ 

        $(value+ '_taskbar').addClass('hover');
    }
    else {
        $(value + '_taskbar').removeClass('hover');
    };
});
```

Comment: @Justastudent just check it now

Comment: @Justastudent thanx buddy

Comment: Just had to change  
"if ( $(value).hasClass("visible")) ) { "
to
"if ( $(value).hasClass("visible")) { "

but this seems to work great.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array like this:

```
$.each(windows,function(i,l) {
  if ($(l).hasClass('visible')) {
    $(l + '_taskbar').addClass('hover');
  } else {
    $(l + '_taskbar').removeClass('hover');
  };
});
```

*Edit: See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) for more.*

Comment: You may want to add a link to the [docs](//api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) in your answer.